# Sync video only streaming using pts

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am using ffmpeg for streaming video alone (no audio) and SDL 2.0 for display. So far, I have decoded the packets as soon as they arrive and present it to the renderer. But I would like to display the video frames by syncing with PTS value so that the receiver does not go out of sync with the sender (Since I am streaming real time video over RTSP). I have read dranger tutorial but I cannot understand it. My pseudo code looks like this:

```
//Create SDL window
SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL", 
SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, w, h, 0); 
//Create renderer for the window
SDL_Renderer * renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0); 

//Allocate frame
frame = avcodec_alloc_frame(); 

//Read frame 
while (av_read_frame(format_context, &avpacket) >= 0) { 
if (avpacket.stream_index == videostream) { 
//Decode the frame
avcodec_decode_video2(codec_context, frame, &frame_finished, 
&avpacket); 
if (frame_finished) {
  //update the YUV texture with the decoded frame (SDL_UpdateYUVTexture)
  //Copy the texture to the renderer (SDL_RendererCopy)
  //Present the rederer (SDL_RenderPresent)
 }

//Handle SDL event
SDL_PollEvent(&event)
}
```

Can one help me how and where I can use PTS in the above code (a pseudo code is much better) and implement the synchronization between sender and receiver (such that if more packets are accumulated in the buffer, I should drop some packets so that latency between sender and receiver does not grow up as the time goes)?

Thanks in advance.